# Basic Angular page crashes

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular (or TypeScript) code compiles and serves, but when I try to load the page in Firefox it crashes.  The code is

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Anguilar</h1>
<dd-button></dd-button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { DdButtonComponent } from './ddButton.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DdButtonComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**ddButton.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dd-button',
  template: "<dd-button>Text</dd-button>"
})
export class DdButtonComponent {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Explaining Modernity';
}
```

Sorry for the likely noobish issue but since there's no error I'm having a hard time searching for what might be causing the issue.  To describe the crash a little more, when I open the page with `localhost:4200` it tries to load and hangs for a few seconds before bringing up the "page crashed" page in Firefox.

Comment: Your `dd-button` component is including a `dd-button`. This will recur infinitely. Do you mean to do `<button>Text</button>` instead?

Comment: @Explosion Pills you are correct. Don't be shy and convert the comment into an answer, as this is the correct answer. This Angular code has infinite recursion and therefore creates a "stack overflow". Pun not intended :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dd-button` component references itself in the template:

```
selector: 'dd-button',
template: '<dd-button>Text</dd-button>',
```

This means that each `dd-button` attempts to render its own `dd-button` infinitely. The browser page crashes once your call stack size gets too big.

Most likely you intended to use `<button>Text</button>`